# Custom loop for Custom Post Type

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, wordpress-theming, custom-post-type

I have a Custom Post Type and the markup/classes need to be slightly different to the standard Post type.

I have a file called loop.php, which I'm assuming specifies the markup for Posts and a Custom Post Type by default will inherit this? If I duplicate this file and rename it, how can I specify that the Custom Post Type uses that template and not the default one? Or is there another (better) way of doing this?

My loop.php looks like this:

```
<?php if (have_posts()): while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

    <!-- article -->
    <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>

        <!-- post thumbnail -->
        <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail()) : // Check if thumbnail exists ?>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">
                <?php the_post_thumbnail(array(120,120)); // Declare pixel size you need inside the array ?>
            </a>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <!-- /post thumbnail -->

        <!-- post title -->
        <h2>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
        </h2>
        <!-- /post title -->

        <!-- post details -->
        <span class="date"><?php the_time('F j, Y'); ?> <?php the_time('g:i a'); ?></span>
        <span class="author"><?php _e( 'Published by', 'html5blank' ); ?> <?php the_author_posts_link(); ?></span>
        <span class="comments"><?php if (comments_open( get_the_ID() ) ) comments_popup_link( __( 'Leave your thoughts', 'html5blank' ), __( '1 Comment', 'html5blank' ), __( '% Comments', 'html5blank' )); ?></span>
        <!-- /post details -->

        <?php html5wp_excerpt('html5wp_index'); // Build your custom callback length in functions.php ?>

        <?php edit_post_link(); ?>

    </article>
    <!-- /article -->

<?php endwhile; ?>

<?php else: ?>

    <!-- article -->
    <article>
        <h2><?php _e( 'Sorry, nothing to display.', 'html5blank' ); ?></h2>
    </article>
    <!-- /article -->

<?php endif; ?>
```

And my Custom Post Type, which is included in the html5blank theme I'm using is as follows:

```
// Create 1 Custom Post type for a Demo, called HTML5-Blank
function create_post_type_html5()
{
    register_taxonomy_for_object_type('category', 'html5-blank'); // Register Taxonomies for Category
    register_taxonomy_for_object_type('post_tag', 'html5-blank');
    register_post_type('html5-blank', // Register Custom Post Type
        array(
        'labels' => array(
            'name' => __('HTML5 Blank Custom Post', 'html5blank'), // Rename these to suit
            'singular_name' => __('HTML5 Blank Custom Post', 'html5blank'),
            'add_new' => __('Add New', 'html5blank'),
            'add_new_item' => __('Add New HTML5 Blank Custom Post', 'html5blank'),
            'edit' => __('Edit', 'html5blank'),
            'edit_item' => __('Edit HTML5 Blank Custom Post', 'html5blank'),
            'new_item' => __('New HTML5 Blank Custom Post', 'html5blank'),
            'view' => __('View HTML5 Blank Custom Post', 'html5blank'),
            'view_item' => __('View HTML5 Blank Custom Post', 'html5blank'),
            'search_items' => __('Search HTML5 Blank Custom Post', 'html5blank'),
            'not_found' => __('No HTML5 Blank Custom Posts found', 'html5blank'),
            'not_found_in_trash' => __('No HTML5 Blank Custom Posts found in Trash', 'html5blank')
        ),
        'public' => true,
        'hierarchical' => true, // Allows your posts to behave like Hierarchy Pages
        'has_archive' => true,
        'supports' => array(
            'title',
            'editor',
            'excerpt',
            'thumbnail'
        ), // Go to Dashboard Custom HTML5 Blank post for supports
        'can_export' => true, // Allows export in Tools > Export
        'taxonomies' => array(
            'post_tag',
            'category'
        ) // Add Category and Post Tags support
    ));
}
```

Once I have that working, I'll also need to pull the posts onto the homepage, a maximum of 3. Can someone help me with this? I think I've got in above my head and I'm struggling big time now!

Let me know if you need anymore info :)

Comment: You want you loop.php to be used in custom-post-type template? or you want custom-post-type page ?

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. I'm not actually sure. I'm a totally novice so I'm happy to go with the preferred/best practice approach. :)